# Including a backslash within lstinline

Tags: listings

This is rather confusing. I have this command:

```
\newcommand*{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
```

If I use it like this:

```
\code{.\foo}
```

It renders thusly:

[image]

Hmmm, OK - I guess `foo` is being interpreted as a command and somehow converting to zero. And if I use it like this:

```
\code{.\textbackslash{}foo}
```

It renders like this:

[image]

Even more confusingly, if I cut out the middleman and do this:

```
\lstinline{.\textbackslash{}foo}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone explain what on Earth is going on here? And, perhaps more importantly, how I can use my `code` command and include a backslash in the code?

Comment: like all other verb commands you can not embed `\lstinline` in the argument of another command.

Comment: `\newcommand*{\code}]{\lstinline}` will work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, and apologies if this stuff is "obvious". I think it's gonna take a while for LaTeX to click with my programmer brain.

Comment: verbatim commands need to change the parser so that `\foo` parses as `\ `, `o`,`o`  not the single token `\foo`  but in your definition the argument has already been scanned with the default tokenization by `\code` and it is those tokens that get passed to `\listinline` so changing the scanner at that point has no effect.