# Using single color for lstinline

Tags: listings

I have the following:

```
\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline}
```

It is (correctly) showing code in black, with keywords in blue. However, I would like *all* inline code to appear in a distinct color (browny/reddish). How can I achieve this?

Note that I **can not** redefine `\code` to look something like this:

```
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}
```

This is because of [this issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/411097/including-a-backslash-within-lstinline), wherein I have inline code snippets that includes backslashes. I started pursuing a solution that uses `\color`, but I couldn't figure out how to do that given the above constraint.

Comment: Maybe you could use optional parameter for `\lstinline` to redefine colors for keywords and other symbols: `\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[keywordstyle=\color{brown}, basicstyle=\color{brown}]}`

Comment: @Ignasi excellent - that worked! Happy to accept as answer if you add one.

Answer (score 4):

You can always add a particular `listing` style into the optional argument of `lstinline`:

```
\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[keywordstyle=\color{brown}, basicstyle=\color{brown}]}
```

In this case, you'll have to define another command when you need other listing settings.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\code}{\lstinline[keywordstyle=\color{brown}, basicstyle=\color{brown}]}

\newcommand*{\codered}{\lstinline[keywordstyle=\color{red}, basicstyle=\color{green}]}

\lstset{
    language=C,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}
    }

\begin{document}

\lstinline{for (i=0; i<5; i++) if (i==0)}

\code{for (i=0; i<5; i++) if (i==0)}

\codered{for (i=0; i<5; i++) if (i==0)}

\end{document}
```

[image]